# How to rewrite asynchronous function (node.js, monk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to write an asynchronous function to give me a random document from a mongodb collection.

```
var getRandDoc = function(){
    var db = monk('localhost/data');
    var coll = db.get('coll');

    coll.count({}, function(err, count){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            coll.find({}, {limit:-1, skip:randomNum(0, count)}, function(err, out){
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else{
                    db.close();
                    return out[0]['name'];
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In another file, I call this function with something like:

```
console.log(test.getRandDoc());
```

And I get `undefined`

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: It returns undefined. I forgot to mention it but edited it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the usual node callback confusion.  If you don't want to use promises then getRandDoc() needs to accept a callback and then call it with the results in the  coll.find(...) method.  So something like this:

```
var getRandDoc = function(cb){
    var db = monk('localhost/data');
    var coll = db.get('coll');

    coll.count({}, function(err, count){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            coll.find({}, {limit:-1, skip:randomNum(0, count)}, function(err, out){
                if (err) return cb(err)
                else{
                    db.close();
                    return cb(null, out[0]['name']);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You probably want to pass back that error too, so:

```
test.getRandDoc(function(err, name){
});
```

A promise based version is going to look something like this:

```
var getRandDoc = function(){
    var db = monk('localhost/data');
    var coll = db.get('coll');
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    coll.count({}, function(err, count){
        if (err) deferred.reject(err);
        else {
            coll.find({}, {limit:-1, skip:randomNum(0, count)}, function(err, out){

                if (err) deferred.reject(err);
                else{
                    db.close();
                    deferred.resolve((out[0]['name']);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
    }
```

But it's still not going to give you a straight forward variable assignment. You'll wind up calling it something like this:

```
test.getRandDoc().then(function(res){}).fail(function(err){});
```

Welcome to node!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I did to debug, but now I need to assign the output of this function to a variable. `var rand = getRandDoc()`. How do I do this?

Comment: You aren't going to get a version that does a simple variable assignment, but you could use a promise. Welcome to node :)!  I will add an example.

Comment: Maybe you can dispatch a custom event at the and of the external file and bind your getRandDoc to it!

Comment: Great answer, I'm going to add a little tidbit that might help - as soon as one callback/anonymous function is introduced into your Node.JS code (which should be very quickly if you're doing things right), always second guess yourself if you have a `return` anywhere in your code, it's quite possibly not meant to be there.